# How to transpose column to row?

Tags: python, csv, transpose

I have the data in a file:

Sample:

```
City Very poor Poor Fair Good Excellent 
Mumbai 0 4 30 58 8 
Delhi 5 7 18 39 31
```

I want to transpose column to row:

```
Mumbai 0 Very poor
Mumbai 4 Poor
Mumbai 30 Fair
Mumbai 58 Good
Mumbai 8 Excellent
.....
.....
```

Is there any function in python which can do this? I have done it in sql using xml path but I don't know best way to do in python.

Comment: Yes, see `pandas.DataFrame.melt`

Comment: Python has a built-in function named [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) which can transpose the rows and columns of a 2D matrix (such as a list-of-lists). If the file is in CSV format, then you can easily read it into such a data-structure using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).module in the standard-library.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using just the `csv` module from the standard library.

For convenience we use `csv.DictReader` to read in and use headers via the `OrderedDict` objects which are returned`.

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""City VeryPoor Poor Fair Good Excellent
Mumbai 0 4 30 58 8
Delhi 5 7 18 39 31""")

# replace mystr with open('file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=' ')
    for line in reader:
        city = line.popitem(last=False)[1]
        for cat, rating in line.items():
            print(city, rating, cat)

Mumbai 0 VeryPoor
Mumbai 4 Poor
Mumbai 30 Fair
Mumbai 58 Good
Mumbai 8 Excellent
Delhi 5 VeryPoor
Delhi 7 Poor
Delhi 18 Fair
Delhi 39 Good
Delhi 31 Excellent
```

Note I have changed your data in a minor way: `VeryPoor` is the category rather than `Very Poor` - you may need to specify specific treatment for non-standard whitespace in headers.